# Converting software RAID1 to RAID10 for /boot

Tags: software-raid

Array info:

`/dev/md0` -> `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`

`/dev/md2` -> `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2`

Partition info:

`/boot` -> `/dev/md0`

`/` -> `/dev/md1`

I have two drives that are setup as RAID1 using software RAID on Redhat. I added two additional drives (same size) and I would like to conver the RAID1 to a RAID10. The problem I'm having is adding the last drive to the array. I've gotten as far as creating a RAID10 with two missing devices but as soon as I add the last drive, all hell breaks loose. It seems /dev/sda1 is the culprit.

What I'm not too sure about is how to create the RAID10. I've tried the following

```
mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=raid10 --raid-device=4 /dev/sdc1 missing /dev/sdd1 missing
```

I then proceeded to fail `/dev/sdb1` from `/dev/md0` and added that partition to `/dev/md2`. I proceeded to install the MBR on EACH partition since boot resides on `/dev/sdx1` on each drive. As a test, all is well, I'm able to boot back into the system once I do a quick reboot. Now, when I go add the last drive `/dev/sda1`, it breaks. I attempted to install grub on `/dev/sda1` and I get the following ...

```
grub> root (hd0,0) /dev/sda
root (hd0,0) /dev/sda
Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0xfd
grub> setup (hd0)
setup (hd0)
Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... no
Checking if "/grub/stage1" exists... no

Error 2: Bad file or directory type
```

At this point, the array is hosed I believe. I rebooted the server and it refuses to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't RAID-0 or RAID-10 the /boot partition.  Under both RAID schemes the data is interleaved across two or more disks -- and when the computer goes to read it, it doesn't know how the data is spread across those disks.

It would be like giving you a box of Alphabits and asking you to construct a document in a foreign language describing how to construct a document out of Alphabits.

Comment: Then why would it work w/ 3 drives but it fails once I add the last drive?